# Why does the regex not see exponents in E or e format

Tags: regex

I am writing a regular expression for real numbers, why does it see symbols of degrees e E?

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?([eE][-+][0-9])?[0-9]*$
```

Example:

```
-12.12
012,123
.123
,512
342.4E-1
--12.12
12
```

Comment: Can you add example strings that should match and fail?

Comment: @RumeOne and from those strings, all should match? Can you clarify?

Comment: @Thefourthbird: I believe that all the lines except `--12.12` should be matched.  The double-dash makes that line invalid (at most one sign at the start of the number).

Answer (score 2):

Your `E`-matching fragment comes before the 'fraction'-matching fragment — it is in the wrong place.  That expression needs to be at the end.  It should match `3E+1` OK as written, but that's not all that you want.

You have:

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?([eE][-+][0-9])?[0-9]*$
```

It should be more like:

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$
```

Note that I added a `+` so that the exponent must have at least one and may have many digits.  And I added a `?` so that the exponent sign is optional.

Given the data file:

```
-12.12
012,123
.123
,512
342.4E-1
--12.12
12
```

running the expression using `grep -E`, I get the output:

```
$ grep -nE -e '^[-+]?[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$' data
1:-12.12
2:012,123
3:.123
4:,512
5:342.4E-1
7:12
$
```

Using `grep -E` means that the RE is being interpreted as a [POSIX Extended Regular Expression (ERE)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html).  The RE above matches an empty string.  This is probably undesirable — but (as noted in a comment) can be fixed using an ERE:

```
^[-+]?([0-9]+[,.]?[0-9]*|[,.][0-9]+)([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$
```

The segment `([0-9]+[,.]?[0-9]*|[,.][0-9]+)` looks for:

- Either a string of one or more digits, optionally followed by a decimal point (either comma or dot) and zero or more fractional digits,
- Or a string starting with a decimal point and followed by one or more fractional digits.

This requires at least one digit — it rules out empty lines (and oddball cases like `E+12` being a valid number).

When your RE is matching the dash character in a character class, you need to be careful.  A simple rule is to always place the dash after the start of the character class — after `[` or `[^`.  The other safe position is just before the `]` at the end of the character class.  Life gets trickier if you also need to match `]` (and `[`) as part of the character class: you end up with things like:

```
[^][-]
```

which is a negated character class matching `]`, `[` and `-`.  Section §9.3.5 ¶7 of the POSIX specification (linked above) covers some of these points.  Yes, considerable care is required.

Comment: Just a remark. Since a dash is used in character class to get a range, it's safer to put it at the end, or backslash it.  And if a regex has everything optional then it'll also match empty lines. Can be solved with a lookahead. F.e. `^(?=.*[0-9])[+-]*[0-9]*(?:[.,][0-9]+)?(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: Agree that caution is needed when matching a dash, but putting it immediately after the `[` or `[^` is safe.  Your 'avoid empty lines' regex uses PCRE notation — it is not clear from the question which dialect of RE is in use, but it fits in with a POSIX ERE (extended regular expression).  It should be possible to stay with an ERE and use a variant of `([0-9]+[,.]?[0-9]*|[,.][0-9]+)`, I think, to demand at least one digit — but I haven't verified that regex against the possible inputs.